# jQuery, Div acts oddly when using .slideUp( );

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying slide a large div until it is hidden but at the very end of the slide animation the top of the div starts to slide downwards for just a second. How do i force the div to only move the bottom part of the div and let the top stay locked?
Here is my code:

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".showBtn").hide();
$(".header").hide();

$(".hideBtn").click(function() {
    $(".hero").slideUp("slow", function() {
        $(".showBtn").show()
        $(".header").show();
    });
});

$(".showBtn").click(function () {
    $(".hero").slideDown();
    $(".showBtn").hide();
    $(".header").hide();
});

});
```

Html

```
    <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="depth" title="Frederik">Frederik</h1>
        <h2>HTML, CSS, Javascript, C#</h2>
        <div class="hideBtn">
            hide
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
    
    </div>
    <div class="showBtn">
        show
    </div>
```

Comment: its margin on the div, try removing the margin. http://jsfiddle.net/zwYC7/

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by a top-margin on your h1, which overflows its parent. Remove the margin, replace it with a padding or add `overflow: hidden;` to the .hero div.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7RVB/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what causes it, but putting a border of the same color of my background always worked for me. I'd put it on the hero class. Hope its possible for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is caused by the header tag. By default, all browsers have margins for headers. All you need to do is add margin:0 to the header tag a the top to combat the issue. I have attached a link to the fixed code example below.

```
<h1 class="depth" style="margin:0;" title="Foo Bar">Foo Bar</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9XHtT/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by absolute/float positioning your div, es:

```
.hero {
  position: absolute;
}
```